# What is the market share for different Ruby versions and implementations?

Tags: ruby

Where can I find reliable statistics for Ruby usage, by versions and implementations?

Comment: If you are considering whether to target 1.8.7, it is not recommended. According to [this news post](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2011/10/06/plans-for-1-8-7/), ruby 1.8.7 will reach definitive EOL by June 2013, and will only receive bugfixes until June 2012. Not to mention it lacks the several improvements present in the 1.9 series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rubygems.org is making statistics on the gem installs. You could ask someone on the team.